# Как вставить в текстовое поле, отмеченные флажком элементы? а если флаг убирается, удалить их

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

Есть список элементов, напротив которых ставятся флаги, при постановке флага элемент должен попадать в текстовое поле, если флаг убирается, то элемент должен удалиться из формы.

Понимаю, что при постановке флага сначала форма должна очищаться, пробовал это реализовать, но либо элементы не заносятся, либо не происходит очистка.

```js
var textArea = $('.text');
$('input').change(function() {
  //textArea.val('');
  $("input:checked").each(function(i) {
    textArea.append($(this).siblings().text() + ';\n');
  })
});
```

```css
textarea.text {
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-item">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <label class="option">Первый элемент</label>
</div>
<div class="form-item">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <label class="option">второй элемент</label>
</div>
<div class="form-item">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <label class="option">Последний элемент</label>
</div>
<textarea class='text'></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var textArea = $('.text');
$('input').change(function() {
  textArea.val('');
  $("input:checked").each(function(i) {
    textArea.val(textArea.val() + $(this).siblings().text() + ';\n');
  })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно поправить селектор, чтобы сразу получать нужные label, воспользоваться [методом map](http://api.jquery.com/map/) для получения массива строк, объединить массив строк с помощью [функции join](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) и вставить полученную строку за один шаг с помощью [функции val](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

```js
var textArea = $('.text');
$('input').change(function() {
  textArea.val($("input:checked + label").map((_, el) => el.textContent + ';').get().join('\n'));
});
```

```css
textarea.text {
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-item">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <label class="option">Первый элемент</label>
</div>
<div class="form-item">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <label class="option">второй элемент</label>
</div>
<div class="form-item">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <label class="option">Последний элемент</label>
</div>
<textarea class='text'></textarea>
```